# How to put a input text with dynamic width in a table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using twitter-bootstrap and I have two tables like this: **http://jsfiddle.net/MELUd/**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" ></td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" ></td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" ></td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" ></td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" ></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td >XS</td>
            <td >XS</td>
            <td >XS</td>
            <td >XS</td>
            <td >XS</td>
            <td >XS</td>
            <td >XS</td>
            <td >XS</td>
            <td >XS</td>
            <td >XS</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The text inputs of the first table does not resizing so the table isn't responsive.
But in the second table example works perfectly with simple text.

How I can make the input text with dynamic width so I'll not see the horizontal scrollbar?

Any help, tip or advice will be appreciated, and if you need more information let me know and i'll edit the post.

Comment: Check out my updated answer with another solution

Comment: Updated answer again to center-align the inputs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the way to do it is to use javascript to change the width dynamically.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
        $(this).width($(this).parent().width()-20);
    });
});
```

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MELUd/1/)

Please adjust your padding and margin accordingly to center the inputs.

Another solution is to display inputs as blocks

```
.table input{
    display:block;
    width:80%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MELUd/4/)

Comment: Thanks @Khanh TO! the second solution rocks! works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

you could either try specifying a max-width to the textboxes, either in px or em.

```
input[type='text']{max-width:4em}
```

I'd say go with em.

Comment: But if the width of the td is higher than 4em the input will not resize to get the maximum.